# np.stack ValueError: need at least one array to stack

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of data processing steps. Towards the end of it is a np.stack but I keep getting ValueError: need at least one array to stack. After investigating, it seems my previous code is not really append data into the array, hence when stacking, it is an empty array. However I cannot find out why the append is not work.

```
def load_data(self, seq_len = 20, overlap_rate = 0.2, augment = False, verbose = False):
        if self.X:
            print("You already have the data")
            return
        df = pd.read_csv(self.data_path)
        if verbose:
            print("the shape of the data is ", df.shape)

        df_arr = df.drop(columns=['id'])
        df = None
        start_idx = 0
        N,D = df_arr.shape#N*4

        df_arr = self.preprocess(df_arr)

        for i in range(1,N,1):
            if verbose and i%10000==0:
                print("load %5d of %5d"%(i,N))
            if int(df_arr.iloc[i,3])==1:#encounter a new sequence
                end_idx = i
                seq = df_arr.iloc[start_idx:end_idx,:]
                while seq.shape[0]>=seq_len+1:
                    self.X_raw.append(seq.iloc[:seq_len,:3])
                    self.X.append(self.noisy(seq.iloc[:seq_len,:3]))
                    self.labels.append(seq.iloc[1:seq_len+1,:3])
                    if augment:
                        self.X_raw.append(self.augment(seq.iloc[:seq_len,:3]))
                        self.X.append(self.augment(self.noisy(seq.iloc[:seq_len,:3])))
                        self.labels.append(self.augment(seq.iloc[1:seq_len+1,:3]))
                    seq = seq[int(seq_len*(1.0 - overlap_rate)):]
                start_idx = end_idx
        if verbose:
            print("load %d sequences of data"%len(self.X))
        self.X = np.stack(self.X, 0)
        self.X_raw = np.stack(self.X_raw, 0)
        self.labels = np.stack(self.labels, 0)


    def preprocess(self, data):
        self.maxZ = np.max(data[:2])
        print(self.maxZ)
        data[:2] = data[:2]/self.maxZ
        data[:0] = data[:0]/1525
        data[:1] = data[:1]/2740
        return data

    def noisy(self, data):
        mean = [0,0,0]
        cov = [[.01/1525,0,0],[0,.01/2740,0],[0,0,.01/self.maxZ]]
        draw = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, data.shape[0])
        '''tmp = data + draw
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2],'r')
        ax.plot(tmp[:,0], tmp[:,1], tmp[:,2],'b')
        ax.set_xlabel('x coordinate')
        ax.set_ylabel('y coordinate')
        ax.set_zlabel('z coordinate')
        plt.show()'''
        return data + draw

    def augment(self, data):
        temp = np.zeros(data.shape)
        temp[:] = data[:]
        temp[:,1] = 1 - data[:,1]
        return temp
```

I think the problem reside in the while loop where append happens in the dataloader part. But I am not able to figure out why.

THe Error Trace back is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-43aa8ee86aef> in <module>
      9 
     10 dl = DataLoad(directory, filename)
---> 11 dl.load_data(config['seq_len'], config['overlap_rate'], augment = True, verbose = False)

~/RNN_tabletennis/dataloader.py in load_data(self, seq_len, overlap_rate, augment, verbose)
     54                 if verbose:
     55                         print("load %d sequences of data"%len(self.X))
---> 56                 self.X = np.stack(self.X, 0)
     57                 self.X_raw = np.stack(self.X_raw, 0)
     58                 self.labels = np.stack(self.labels, 0)

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    420     arrays = [asanyarray(arr) for arr in arrays]
    421     if not arrays:
--> 422         raise ValueError('need at least one array to stack')
    423 
    424     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}

ValueError: need at least one array to stack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains `self.X = np.stack(self.X, 0)`.

Note that:

- this is the only point where you create *self.X*,
- but in this instruction you also **refer** to *self.X*, so it should be
  created somewhere earlier.

Check whether the "initial creation" of *self.X* actually takes place.

My first suspicion is that *self.X* is *None* when you attempt to execute the offending instruction.

Another hints are:

- Set *verbose* to *True*. At least you will have some trace printouts.
- To allow some experiments with your code:

  - Reveal *seq_len* and *overlap_rate* parameters from your *config*.
  - Provide some input data, of limited size.
  - Put the full content of your class.

And a couple of hints concerning `if self.X:`:

1. Your *self.X* variable is certainly defined. Otherwise you would have
   received *NameError* exception.
2. Probably it is *None*, so that `if self.X:` does not return earlier.
3. If *X* was set as a non-empty Dataframe (containing some rows), you would
   have got *ValueError* exception.
4. The same exception occurs if *X* is an empty DataFrame.
5. Maybe you should:

   - Assume that *X* is a DataFrame (maybe it is created in the class
     constructor).
   - Check whether it contains some rows. E.g. check *df.index.size*.
     In the boolean context, on a non-empty DataFrame, the result is *True*.

Comment: Hi Yes the self.X is defined in the def __init__, self.X = []. But the while look self.X.append should give it a values appended. However it seems not? I turned the verbose to true, and it give me similar issue in the np.stack(self.X, 0)

Comment: With the verbose on the print load is working, towards end it gives me "load 590000 of 600000
load 0 sequences of data" then trace back to the np.stack(self.X, 0) error again

Comment: Before you call *self.X = np.stack(self.X, 0)*, check whether *self.X* is not an empty list. It seems that the problem occurs on the last "chunk" of your source data.